# upload and read file in nodejs without any third party module like multer, express-fileupload, busyboy etc,

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I'm currently learning nodejs file upload. I saw a lot of tutorials, but all the tutorials force me to use third-party module mainly **multer**. I need to upload and read files, but I need to do it myself

Answer (score 0):

Multer uses busboy internally, busboy uses node writableStream api, if you want to understand how they are doing, go through busboy code. Unless you have some custom usecase and understand streams very well it's not recommended to use your custom implementation. https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/blob/master/lib/main.js